# ImageList (VB.Net Winforms) causing Out of Memory errors

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, imagelist

I have a simple process where an ImageList (ImageList1) is populated with images from the database when the form Loads.
These images are then used to change the background of a PictureBox everytime a new record is loaded in the screen.

```
    Dim imageIndex As Integer = ImageList1.Images.IndexOfKey(myDt.Rows(0).Item("Id").ToString)
    If imageIndex <> -1 Then
        PicBox1.BackgroundImage = ImageList1.Images(imageIndex)
    Else
        PicBox1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
    End If
```

After some time of using this screen, we will eventually have this error:
[image]

Do you find anything in the code above that could be causing a memory leak? What can I do about this?

Comment: How many images you load? Do you really need to load all?

Comment: Show your code, i guess there is a loop and you always access the first row at `myDt.Rows(0)`

Comment: There is no loop, myDt.Rows(0) is the only row with the details for the screen populate.

Comment: 11 small images - 40kb each. They are stored in the database and we opted to use an imagelist to minimize the nr of calls to the database. 
This screen populates (which sets the picturebox background image) an avg of 5 time per minute.

Comment: Well, you can imagine that the code you have shown is not responsible for the `OutOfMemoryException`. So you have to show more. Where you populate the list? How you load the image? Do you have looked at the task manager or used a memory profiler? Where you consume the memory? How much memory is available at all?

Comment: You are not calling Dispose(), very important for bitmaps.  Using ImageList to store the images is certainly one reason to get this easily wrong, it should only ever be used to provide icons for the TreeView and ListView controls.  Use a List(Of Image) instead, now you can ignore the need to call Dispose() until the FormClosed event.  Use a memory profiler if you still have trouble.  Or remove the jitter forcing so your program can run in 64-bit mode.